# I have installed git in ubuntu and I cloned a project, but is locked and I can't make changes to the folder

Tags: git, ubuntu

I've just cloned a read-only project and the folder has lock on it and I cannot even delete. It says permission denied. I've tried shift-delete but only deleted some files, not all. I'm very new to Ubuntu so I don't know what to do, for now I renamed and cloned a read-write project again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open a Terminal : Ctrl+Alt+T
2. Use CD command to get to directory (it defaults to your home directory, e.g. if it's in a subfolder called MyFolder do "cd MyFolder"
3. Type sudo rm -R projectname and it will request you type your password.

Answer (score 1):

firstly, your question is more suitable to [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/),
secondly, have you tried to `sudo rm -rf project-folder`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try providing super user permissions...

```
    sudo rm -rf /file/you/want/to/delete
```